# CP2K Spherical Cell

Tags: software, gas-phase-chemistry

I'm trying to run a gas phase cluster calculation in CP2K. I want to create an outside force to constrain water molecules that are in the simulation within a radius of a central ion. I want to create a spherical cell of a given radius $\lambda$, fix the ion in the center and then run QMMD with the waters free to do their motion.

Does anyone know how to create a spherical cell for the simulation with no periodic boundary conditions or a better way to impose this clustering constraint $\lambda$?

Comment: Since this is more about how to use a particular modeling program, rather than about the chemical system being studied, I think this would be a better fit on [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)